# Get terminal application name from shell

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, command-line

I am used to my `osascript` aliases. In particular, I have `nx` for opening new tab and closing the old one.

However, my scripts use application name to send keyboard signals to it. Instead of writing it all many times i use my own variable `term` that contains terminal application name (it is always `term=iTerm`, no matter what terminal I'm using).

How do I fetch the terminal emulator's name I am entering command line with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TERM_PROGRAM` is set by both Terminal and iTerm:

```
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
```